# Mixamo animation when merging with original model binds wrong pose

Tags: animation, rigging, mixamo

[image]

The original model i.e Armature(.glb file) when the animation of Armature.001(.fbx file) is added to the Armature. I don't understand why it binds the wrong pose. I checked the armatures of both files they are identical.

Steps to reproduce this error:

1. Rename the animation - waving
2. Select Armature then Dopesheet-> Action editor
3. Select the animation

[image]

Comment: Hello! Set both armatures to the *Rest Position* and you see the problem. One is in A-pose and the other one is in T-pose. The target armature must have the same rest pose that was used for the animation data (T-pose).